# How to store node level in dfs tree without violating O(|V | + |E|)

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

Is there a way to store the level of each vertex in the DFS tree it belongs to with it?

The time complexity should be `O(|V| + |E|)`.

Comment: While computing the DFS tree, can't you carry the current level as a parameter in the recursive function?

Comment: @Alex L im not sure. i was thinking maybe every time a vertex is pushed onto the stack a counter is increased by 1 and every time an element is popped the counter decreased by one?

Answer (score 0):

This is standard DFS pseudocode from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode):

```
1  procedure DFS(G,v):
2      label v as discovered
3      for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
4          if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
5              recursively call DFS(G,w)
```

To add level:

```
1  procedure DFS(G,v,level):
2      label v as discovered
3      v.level = level
4      for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
5          if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
6              recursively call DFS(G,w,level+1)
```

Start by calling `DFS(G,v,0)`